# Understanding the structure of Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

As I am going through the website: 
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall14/cos326/sec/03/precept03_sol.ml

I have got a question according to the Ocaml structure. To be more specific, I have questions according to the code:

```
let rec reduce (f:'a -> 'b -> 'b) (u:'b) (xs:'a list) : 'b =
    match xs with
    | [] -> u
    | hd::tl -> f hd (reduce f u tl);;
```

What does the `f hd` do at the very last line? (I understand that `reduce f u tl` is calling the function itself again.)

My second question is how to use a function to implement another function in Ocaml. For the code:

```
let times_x (x: int) (lst: int list) : int list =  
  map (fun y -> y*x) lst
```

What does `fun y -> y*x` do? what does `lst` do at the end of the code?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I figured out that "map (fun y -> y*x) lst" is applying the function" map (fun y -> y*x)" to the value "lst".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that has been provided is a reduce function that takes three parameters - a function that maps inputs of type `'a` and `'b` to an output of type `'b`, a value of type `'b`, and as list of elements of type `'a`.

For example, the `length` example from the lecture:

```
let length (lst: int list) : int = 
  reduce (fun _ len -> len + 1) 0 lst
```

The first parameter to `reduce` is a function that, when given two parameters, discards the first one and returns the second parameter incremented by one. The second is a value (0) to be used as an accumulator. The third is a list to find the length of.

The behavior of this recursive `reduce` function is to return the second parameter (an accumulator as used in the length example) once the provided list is empty, and otherwise run the provided function using the head of the list and the recursed value.

Once again going to the `length` example, say we give it a list with a single element `[1]`.

Our call to `length` becomes `reduce (fun _ len -> len + 1) 0 [1]`

Recall `reduce`:

```
let rec reduce (f:'a -> 'b -> 'b) (u:'b) (xs:'a list) : 'b =
    match xs with
    | [] -> u
    | hd::tl -> f hd (reduce f u tl);;
```

First, we match `[1]` against `[]`, which fails. Since it is a non-empty list, we run `f hd (reduce f u tl)`

Recall that `f` is the parameter that `length` provided: `fun _ len -> len + 1`

Therefore, we effectively run the following:

```
(fun _ len -> len + 1) 1 (reduce (fun _ len -> len + 1) 0 [])
```

In this case, the `length` function discards the first parameter since the values in the list are not necessary to know the length of the list.

The recursive portion will match against `[]` and return the value of `u` at the time, which is 0.

Therefore, one level up, `(fun _ len -> len + 1) 1 (reduce (fun _ len -> len + 1) 0 [])` becomes `(fun _ len -> len + 1) 1 0` and returns `0 + 1`, simplifying to our expected value 1, which represents the length of the list.

---

Now, to your second question, in regards to `times_x`. This performs a mapping. For example, we can map `[1;2;3;4;5]` to `[3;6;9;12;15]` with a mapping `fun x -> x * 3`.

Here `times_x` is defined as follows:

```
let times_x (x: int) (lst: int list) : int list =
  map (fun y -> y*x) lst
```

`times_x` takes an integer and a list. Using the above example, we could call it with `times_x 3 [1;2;3;4;5]` to get `[3;6;9;12;15]`.

Beyond this I recommend looking into how map and reduce functions work in general.

I hope this answer was adequate at addressing your question.

Comment: Thank you for your explicit answer!! The part bugs me is "(fun _ len -> len + 1)". Is "(fun _ len -> len + 1)" same as f? I have seen you mentioned " discards the first one and returns the second parameter incremented by one". What are the exact inputs of this parameter, which is a function, to take in?

Comment: I guess my question really is what the structure is of "fun_len".

Comment: `fun _ len -> len + 1` is a function. In OCaml, functions are first class citizens and can be passed as parameters to other functions, etc. To be more precise, `_` is just the professor's way of saying 'anything goes here' - they could have just as easily used `fun unused_value input_value -> input_value + 1`